# WP8 dynamic number of panorama items based on list size

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, binding, panoramas

I'm creating an app which shows the status of a number of servers. This information is retrieved from an API and stored in an observable collection (ObservableCollection) on my view model.

Each instance of the ServerDetails Object should have a PanoramaItem. I'm trying to do this through Binding in the xaml.

Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: Depending on the number, then you should maybe think about pivots instead

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.. here is a helpful blog, WP7 but will be relevant for WP8
http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2012/08/22/data-binding-to-the-panorama-control-in-wp7.aspx

basically, you need to set the ItemSource, and a DataTemplate / ItemTemplate for the panorama items.  The method is the same with Pivot/Pivot Items there are also plenty of blogs for those.